# c# uwp GridView custom panel

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I'm still struggling with my custom panel for my GridView (see other question: [UWP c# Binding to ItemsPanel / Custom Panel (Template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731358/uwp-c-sharp-binding-to-itemspanel-custom-panel-template))

I have set up my GridView with my custom panel. Now if I switch my GridView Selection Mode from 'Multiple' to 'Single' and vice-versa, the items in the custom panels are not updated automatically => the 'selection square' doesn't show/hide for all items at once, only if I runs my mouse over it.

This doesn't happe if I use an ItemsWrapGrid for instance... Which Event /Method do I need to implement in the custom panel?

So far my code of the panel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using teachers_cal;
using teachers_cal.Classes;

namespace teachers_cal.UserControls
{
public class PRGD010_GridViewPanel : Panel
{
    public int NumberRowsOrColumns
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(NumberRowsOrColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NumberRowsOrColumnsProperty, value < 1 ? 0 : value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberRowsOrColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NumberRowsOrColumns", typeof(int), typeof(PRGD010_GridViewPanel), new PropertyMetadata(1, OnNumberRowsOrColumnsPropertyChanged));
    private static void OnNumberRowsOrColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (source as PRGD010_GridViewPanel).InvalidateMeasure();
    }

    public int Offset
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StartPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartPositionProperty, value >= this.NumberRowsOrColumns ? this.NumberRowsOrColumns - 1 : value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Offset", typeof(int), typeof(PRGD010_GridViewPanel), new PropertyMetadata(0, OnStartPositionPropertyChanged));
    private static void OnStartPositionPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (source as PRGD010_GridViewPanel).InvalidateMeasure();
    }

    public PRGD010_GridViewPanel()
    {
    }

    /// Get Items Source count items
    private int GetItemsCount()
    {
        return this.Children != null ? this.Children.Count : 0;
    }

    /// Get Calculated Row or Column count. Depending on Offset, Numbers and Items
    private int GetRowsOrColumnsCount()
    {
        int additionalLine = ((GetItemsCount() + this.Offset)) % this.NumberRowsOrColumns > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        return ((GetItemsCount() + this.Offset)) / this.NumberRowsOrColumns + additionalLine;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Arrange all items
    /// </summary>
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {

        // Clip to ensure items dont override container
        this.Clip = new RectangleGeometry { Rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height) };

        Double positionTop = 0d;
        double positionGrid = this.Offset;
        double test = this.NumberRowsOrColumns;

        // Must Create looping items count
        foreach (UIElement item in this.Children)
        {
            if (item == null)
                continue;

            Size desiredSize = item.DesiredSize;

            if (double.IsNaN(desiredSize.Width) || double.IsNaN(desiredSize.Height)) continue;

            // Get rect position
            var rect = new Rect(positionGrid * desiredSize.Width, positionTop, desiredSize.Width, desiredSize.Height);
            item.Arrange(rect);

            // set internal CompositeTransform to handle movement
            TranslateTransform compositeTransform = new TranslateTransform();
            item.RenderTransform = compositeTransform;

            if (positionGrid < this.NumberRowsOrColumns - 1) { positionGrid += 1; }
            else
            {
                positionGrid = 0;
                positionTop += desiredSize.Height;
            }
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Measure items 
    /// </summary>
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {

        //Size s = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);

        // set good cliping
        //this.Clip = new RectangleGeometry { Rect = new Rect(0, 0, s.Width, s.Height) };

        // Measure all items
        foreach (UIElement container in this.Children)
        {
            container.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        }

        double width = Children[0]?.DesiredSize.Width ?? 0;
        double height = Children[0]?.DesiredSize.Height ?? 0;
        var i = GetRowsOrColumnsCount();

        return (new Size(width * (double)NumberRowsOrColumns, height * (double)GetRowsOrColumnsCount()));
        //return (new Size(3000, 3000));
    }
}
}
```

EDIT:
I've created two simple projects. Even with standard ItemPanels I got strange behavior. It's really frustrating

1. Using the GridView with a VariableSizeWrapGrid the GridViewItems will not be refresh properly when I change SelectionMode
2. Doing the same with ItemsWrapGrip is okay. Changing SelectionMode will be displayed correctly...

Could someone figure out why this happens? And what to do?!

See the two links...

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4305F58623B1701D!42317&authkey=!APnPBY_9SNDS4AI&ithint=file%2czip

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4305F58623B1701D!42316&authkey=!AMDZtSBQ5bjWaoU&ithint=file%2czip

Thanks for your reply